# Array copying and deleting

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have setup NSCopying and I can copy an array successfully.

```
theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:results.availableData 
copyItems:YES];
```

When I am finished with theArray and all its data is junk I would like to get another fresh copy of the data from results.availableData array.

Whats the best and safest way to do this?

Should i

```
[theArray release];
theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:results.availableData 
copyItems:YES];
```

So release theArray then alloc and init it again?

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply:

```
[theArray setArray: [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: results.availableData
    copyItems: YES] autorelease]];
```

And be done with it.

Comment: The NSMutableArray copies and worked perfect. I use change and delete objects in the array. Later on I want to get a NEW copy of the data from results.availableData. Dont see why I need to alloc again if I haven't released.  Sorry if I failed at expressing the question correctly. Or are you trying to say the way I first alloc and init is wrong?

Comment: @Code - What this example is doing is: (1) allocate a temporary array, copying items from `results.availableData`, (2) replace the contents of `theArray` with the contents of the temporary array, (3) autorelease the temporary. This is an alternative to releasing/re-alloc'ing `theArray`, as you were doing.

Comment: But shouldnt it be a NSMutableArray because I will need to remove objects from the array? Or am I missing something? The theArray is an NSMutableArray for that reason.